# Store and append numpy array in azure blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to iterate through list of image convert it to numpy.darray and store it in azure blob storage. Every loop i want to append np.array to azure blob. The over all goal is to imerge all images in y axis through azure blob.

Comment: Did you mean that convert image to array and append np.array, then upload it to azure blob?

Comment: Yes to concat multiple images

Comment: Every iteration bas to upload image to the same azure blob file

Answer (score 1):

The simple demo could help. For converting image to an array, install Pillow to use PIL by `pip install Pillow` first.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np
import os

account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your access key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)
 
FilePathlist = ['xxxxx', 'xxxxx']
 
blob = []

for filePath in FilePathlist :
 
    print(filePath)
    # load the image
    image = Image.open(filePath)
    
    # convert image to numpy array
    data = asarray(image)

    # append np.array
    blob = np.append(blob, data)

# Upload to blob
print("upload")
blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name, "aaaaa.jpg", blob.tobytes())
```

I tried this, and upload them to the blob.

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Uploading array as a .jpg image to Azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994416/13308381)

Doc [numpy.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

[Convert image to NumPy Array](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/importing-image-data-into-numpy-arrays)

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you Pamela but i want to append array not create new everyloop. I have chunk of images which i will loop and append to azure blob. Final image result will a single image on azure blob.

Comment: Hi, @Somup I edit the code in my answer, just change the loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i think still my question is not answered. I need to upload the array to azure blob every iteration. Since i am running the code on azure function with limited memory i cant append np array to local variable. The file on azure blob grows until iteration complets.

Comment: The folder will contain multiple png and every iteration must append np.darray to same azure blob file

Comment: You could try [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160041/13308381) using less memory instead of `np.append`.

Comment: No it might not help. I need to iterate and append the new array to azure blob. It would be chunk upload. Thanks